# Find header of Clicked Radio Button

Tags: jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've just started with Google Tag Manager and I needs a bit of help. I wanna build it all with Jquery and it would work something like this:

```
$('input[type=radio]').on("click", function() {
dataLayer.push({ 
"event":"Google Event", 
"eventCategory":"Google Category", 
"eventAction":  "Event Action", 
"eventLabel": "Desired Label of Radio Button"
})
});
```

Now what I want to do is be able to attach the label of the radio button to the eventLabel. Can I do it within the:

```
"eventLabel": "Desired Label of Radio Button"
```

or do I need to make a new function above which tracks in and then insert the variable into eventLabel ?

Comment: Do you need the text of the Radio button that was clicked, or the text inside the <label for="..."> Element matching the input?

Comment: The text inside <label for"..."> :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this (unable to recreate a proper testing setup from where I am -- there might be some glitches):

```
$('input[type=radio]').on('click', function () {
   var inputElement = $(this);
   var inputID = inputElement.attr('id');

   var labelElement = $('label[for="' + inputID + '"]');
   var labelText = labelElement.text();

   dataLayer.push({ 
     'event': 'Google Event', 
     'eventCategory': 'Google Category', 
     'eventAction':  'Event Action', 
     'eventLabel': labelText 
   });
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, 10/10